# Python: El programa de suma devuelve "None"

Tags: python, poo

Estoy intentando crear una clase que me pida el nombre de un producto y su precio y que otra clase coja los valores y los sume. Sin embargo, uno ambas clases pero no logro que me muestre la suma, solo me dice 'none'. Soy nuevo en python y me falta todavía manejo en este lenguaje.

```
class Producto:

    def __init__(self,precio='no-definido'):
        self.producto=[]
        self.precio=[]
        for i in range (0,2):
            self.producto.append(str(input('Dame el nombre del producto: ')))
            self.precio.append(float(input('Dame el precio del producto: ')))

class Yogur(Producto):
    def __init__(self,precio):
        super().__init__(precio=precio)

    def total(self):
        self.suma_total = []
        for i in self.precio:
            self.suma_total += self.precio

listado=Yogur(precio='precio')
print(listado.precio)
print(listado.total())
```

¿En qué estoy fallando?
Me gustaría saber cual es mi fallo para evitar cometerlo más
Gracias de antemano

Comment: estás sumando valores, pero en ningún momento le dices que imprima valores

Comment: hay distintas cosas a considerar: si la clase es Producto, ¿por qué esa clase almacena una lista de productos? Lo suyo sería hacer una lista de objetos. De este modo, podrías iterar sobre los productos `p` e ir sumando precios con `p.precio`. Después, en la clase `Yogur` llamas a __init__() innecesariamente, la superclase ya hace eso. ¿Cuál es la tarea exacta que quieres resolver?

Comment: Respetando lo que tienes: si no retornas en el método `total`, cuando ejecute `print(listado.total())`, te imprimirá `None` porque ese método no devuelve nada, además, `self.suma_total` es una lista y `self.precio` también, si pones `self.suma_total += self.precio`, obtendrás en `self.suma_total` una lista con los valores de `self.precio` duplicados (son 2 #s). Si lo que deseas es obtener la suma de precios: inicializas `self.suma_total=0` y dentro del `for`: `self.suma_total += i` y fuera del `for`: `return self.suma_total`. Otra forma es que `total` sólo tenga: `return sum(self.precio)`

Comment: @Firefly he entendido ambas alternativas que me has dado, muy buena respuesta explicandome cada error que he cometido. Por favor, pon esta respeusta como respuesta de la pregunta y te la valido como solución a la pregunta. Gracias de nuevo por aclararmelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respetando lo que tienes: si no retornas en el método total, cuando ejecute `print(listado.total())`, te imprimirá `None` porque ese método no devuelve nada, además, `self.suma_total` es una lista y `self.precio` también, si pones `self.suma_total += self.precio`, obtendrás en `self.suma_total` una lista con los valores de `self.precio` duplicados, porque tiene dos elementos. Si lo que deseas es obtener la suma de precios:

```
def total(self):
    self.suma_total = 0
    for i in self.precio:
        self.suma_total += i
    return self.suma_total
```

Otra forma:

```
def total(self):
    return sum(self.precio)
```